# Find the set of limit points of X

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

$X = U_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (n,n+3)$, where $U$ is union. So $(1,4)\cup (2,5) \cup \text{etc}$. I answered it $\mathbb{N}$ and was wrong with the correct answer being $[1,\infty)$. In my analysis class, we consider $\mathbb{N}$ to start at 1.

My question is, am I wrong? Isn't $\mathbb{N}=[1,\infty)$?

Comment: Do you know what $\mathbb{N}$ and $[1,\infty)$ mean?

Comment: $$\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\cdots \} \ne [1,\infty) = \{a \in \mathbb{R} | 1 \le a\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2.5\in X$ but $2.5 \not \in \mathbb{N}$.